# Xcode - UIImage Preset Apple Textures

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uicolor

Is there any way of accessing the preset UIColor Textures, then setting them as a background? Sort of like this:

```
UIColor *mytexture = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageWithData:mytexture];
[outletWallpaper setImage:myimage];
```

Thanks in advance,
Declan

Comment: Beware that in iOS 7 all Apple textures have been removed and most are now using white of some king blurred transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `backgroundColor` of the view to the texture colour you require.

```
outletWallpaper.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
```

In addition you can load your own images and use them as a `UIColour` by using the `[UIColour -colorWithPatternImage:]` API:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anImageFile"];
UIColour colourPattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: myImage];

outletWallpaper.backgroundColor = colourPattern;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create category of UIImage with method like this:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```